# Quartz crystal resonance frequency simulation

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, crystals, piezoelectric

Is there an open source/scientific software package that would allow to simulate Quartz crystal resonance frequency for specific cut angle, crystal geometry and temperature? How would one approach such task?

I am interested to search for non-standard crystal orientations with interesting features.

End goal would be to receive a graph like this one (image from [here](https://circuitcellar.com/insights/tech-the-future/the-future-of-temperature-compensated-crystal-oscillators/)):

[image: https://circuitcellar.com/insights/tech-the-future/the-future-of-temperature-compensated-crystal-oscillators/]

Comment: You need something capable of calculating mechanical (eigen-) modes of a solid object, given elasticity etc. In case of crystal it will all have to be tensor-valued. Pretty sure [COMSOL](https://www.comsol.com/structural-mechanics-module) could do it, but it is not free. Perhaps it will give you some ideas of where to start

Comment: Im confused about exact application. The crystal is being cut to specifications to be used in a product? And the manufacturing is being hampered by it vibrating at resonant freq? And the cutting will compensate for that via changing the operational frequency of the manufacturing?

Comment: I mean I understand them as timers, but why being cut. Is that dumb question. Also How small are these? Abacus doesnt go that low.

Comment: @AlBrown By changing cut angles you can change properties of the quartz resonator. The most obvious property is temperature coefficient of resonance frequency (i.e. SC vs AT cut, but there are lots of variations of both).

Comment: @Cryo Please promote your comment to answer, otherwise we'll loose bounty... :-)